# Flutter Snapshot.data showing error as argument type ‘string’

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

In my flutter project I keep receiving the following error

```
error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (argument_type_not_assignable)
```

I am not sure what is the reason for it I am following the https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

I find many answers showing that the String might be an empty one. I got the classes from converting the Json to Dart so it should be correct.

```
Future<User> fetchUser() async {
  final response = await http.get(url);
 
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
 
class User {
  int? pk;
  String? username;
 
  User({this.pk, this.username});
 
  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    pk = json['pk'];
    username = json['username'];
  }
 
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['pk'] = this.pk;
    data['username'] = this.username;
    return data;
  }
}
 
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});
 
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
 
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late Future<User> futureUser;
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureUser = fetchUser();
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<User>(
            future: futureUser,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.username); <------------------------- here is the error
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
 
              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Above flutter version 2.12 supports null-safety code. String? takes null value whereas String doesn't take null value. You can either use "!" symbol to make String? value to non-nullable type or you need to change the declaration String to String?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User {
  int? pk;
  String? username; // username is nullable 
                    //Text() data only accepts String not String? 
  User({ this.pk,this.username });
}
```

you can either change your model to

```
class User {
  final int pk;
  final String username; 
                   
  User({required this.pk,
        required this.username,
  });
}
```

or

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.username??'noname');
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
```